# Approval Workflow | Easier Task Response for Managers

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've created an approval workflow in Sharepoint to request time-off. The workflow is tied to a list on a Sharepoint page. I have created two views for the list - one of all requests sent out by the user and one view of all requests sent to the user. The workflow works as intended - the user is easily able to send time-off requests to their manager.

When a request is sent, the workflow assigns a new task to the manager. The manager is alerted via email, and can also view all requests sent to them on the page with the two list views.

The problem lies in the acceptance of the tasks. As of now, if the manager wants to respond to the request, he/she must navigate through 3 different web pages to get to the page with the options to accept/decline.

Clicks on 'Pending Managers Approval' -> Clicks 'Respond to Time-Off Request' -> Clicks "Edit Item' in the View tab -> Selects 'Accept' or 'Decline'

Is there a way for managers to respond to the tasks on the list, or, can I provide a link to the final task page on the list? Any other suggestions to streamline the approval process would be appreciated.

[image]